# Pyspark how to multiply one column with the result from another column -count in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have this DF `salesDF`:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---+----------+-------------------+
|customer_id|customer_name|   email_address|shipping address|product_id|product_name|product_Category|qty|unit_price|          Timestamp|
+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---+----------+-------------------+
|        301|       Jaison|jaison@gmail.com|       Bangalore|       402|      Laptop|     Electronics|  2|     28000|2017-03-10 07:29:00|
|        321|         Abji| Abhji@gmail.com|       Bangalore|       402|      Laptop|     Electronics|  2|     28000|2017-03-12 10:29:00|
|        302|          Tom|   tom@gmail.com|       Bangalore|       601|      Mobile|     Electronics|  1|     20000|2017-03-10 08:29:00|
|        303|       Thomas|thomas@gmail.com|         Chennai|       402|      Laptop|     Electronics|  2|     38000|2017-03-10 08:45:00|
|        307|        Vijay| vijay@gmail.com|         Chennai|       503|          TV|     Electronics|  1|     42000|2017-03-11 09:45:00|
|        310|       Thomas|thomas@gmail.com|         Chennai|       503|          TV|     Electronics|  1|     42000|2017-03-12 09:45:00|
|        308|        Menon| menon@gmail.com|       Hyderabad|       503|          TV|     Electronics|  2|     40000|2017-03-13 09:45:00|
+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---+----------+-------------------+
```

I am looking to find the total number of product sold in day.
The product are purchased by customer with different quantity in each day
so we have to calculate the total count of same product * qty

Below what i tried to get the count

```
sale_of_product_in_a_day =sales_df.groupBy(F.substring('Timestamp', 0,10).alias('Per Day'),'product_name').count()
```

This basically give the result as

```
+----------+------------+-----+
|   Per Day|product_name|count|
+----------+------------+-----+
|2017-03-12|      Laptop|    1|
|2017-03-13|          TV|    1|
|2017-03-12|          TV|    1|
|2017-03-10|      Mobile|    1|
|2017-03-10|      Laptop|    2|
|2017-03-11|          TV|    1|
+----------+------------+-----+
```

The above result based on the grouping of same product with out considering the 'qty' column..
so i need to calculate 'qty' against the number of actual product the customer have purchased in day?

so here in the case the expected result for the date '2017-03-10' should be '4' instead of '2' since the 'quantity' of 'Laptop' was 4

## Expected

```
|2017-03-10|      Laptop|    2| # should be ---> 4
```

so how can multiply one column with the result of count in dataframe? or what is the approach to solve this?

Appreciate if anybody can help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please check and let us know if the solution worked for you ? Will appreciate if you could accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the working solution for you, just use **`groupBy()`** and **`sum()`**

## Create the DF Here

```
    df = spark.createDataFrame([("2017-03-10","Laptop", 2),("2017-03-12","Laptop", 2),("2017-03-10","Mobile", 1),("2017-03-10","Laptop", 2),("2017-03-11","TV",1),("2017-03-12","TV",1),("2017-03-13","TV",2)],[ "col1","col2", "qty"])
df.show(truncate=False)
df_grp =df.groupBy("col1", "col2").agg(F.sum("qty").alias("tot_qty"))
df_grp.show()
```

## Input

```
    +----------+------+---+
|col1      |col2  |qty|
+----------+------+---+
|2017-03-10|Laptop|2  |
|2017-03-12|Laptop|2  |
|2017-03-10|Mobile|1  |
|2017-03-10|Laptop|2  |
|2017-03-11|TV    |1  |
|2017-03-12|TV    |1  |
|2017-03-13|TV    |2  |
+----------+------+---+
```

## Output

```
+----------+------+-------+
|      col1|  col2|tot_qty|
+----------+------+-------+
|2017-03-12|Laptop|      2|
|2017-03-13|    TV|      2|
|2017-03-12|    TV|      1|
|2017-03-10|Mobile|      1|
|2017-03-10|Laptop|      4|
|2017-03-11|    TV|      1|
+----------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @dsk .. it got worked.. so ideally when we group the column, we can apply the sum on associated column.. right?

Comment: That's a correct understanding .. why my answer got downvoted :( can u pls check

Comment: Hi @dsk, i am not sure what happend with vote.. can you please check if you see the answer is upvoted.. or otherwise let me know..Thanks

Comment: you just need to hit the upper arrow button - left hand side